# The wave function of transverse one is different from longitude one for convenience?

Tags: waves, wavefunction

I use the book Fundamental of Physics Hallidays&Resnick 10th Edition Jearl Walker to study in my physics class while I got myself University Physics with Modern Physics Sears, Zemansky 13th Edition for some cases that the former book explain not clearly. In the former one, the function of transverse wave is

$$y(x,t)=Asin(kx+wt)$$

It says that for transverse wave, people use sin in transverse wave function while cosine for longitude wave instead for convenience while in latter one it use $y(x,t)=Acos(kx+wt)$ for transverse wave function

So I want to ask is it true that using sin for transverse wave and cosine for longitude wave have some conveniences? What is those conveniences while both is sinusoidal?

Fix the title if you find it inappropriate

Comment: I have never heard of such a convention and I don't know where the authors came up with it. In theoretical physics it is much more customary to perform all of these calculations with complex numbers, where the waves are written as $e^{i(kx+\omega t)}$

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such convention. The sine and cosine functions can be used interchangably since:

$$ \cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}) $$

So simply changing the origin for the time or $x$ coordinate can switch the equation describing the wave between sine and cosine.

As CuriousOne says in a comment, it's common to describe the wave by a complex exponential:

$$ y(x, t) = e^{i(kx+\omega t)} $$

It's not obvious why this should work until you spot that [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) can be used to rewrite the equation as:

$$ y(x, t) = \cos(kx+\omega t) + i\sin(kx+\omega t) $$

Using the exponential form often makes the algebra a lot simpler (fewer obscure trigonometric identities to remember! :-). Depending on the application we either take only the real part of the final result or for quantities that are not observable, like a wave function, we can leave it as a complex number.